Refresh Data in a 2nd Instance using Macro in 1st Instance
I have an excel file (instance #1) with code to refresh data for any open Excel file that is separate from this one.
Problem is, the other Excel file that is open was from SharePoint, so its a second instance of Excel (instance #2). My current code does not recognize instance #2. The refresh would work if the 2nd file wasnt in a separate instance.
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks

'***** Skip the "Main" workbook. Proceed for any other open workbook *****
If wb.Name <> "Main.xlsb" Then
    '***** Refresh all data connections. *****
    wb.RefreshAll
    wb.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
        '***** Loop until the workbook calculation status is "Done" *****
        Do Until wb.Application.CalculationState = xlDone
        Loop
End If

Next wb

I was thinking that I would need to incorporate GetObject(,"Excel.Application") but I'm not sure how to loop through the possible instances. Also, the name of the file would be different each time, so I can't use the file path - I would like to use "excel file that isn't this current file".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78484591/478884 has code for getting a collection of all open Excel instances.  Once you have that you can find the workbook of interest in the second instance.

@TimWilliams thank you. I used the info on the link you provided, along with another post to (I think) find a solution. I will post the solution.

I believe I've found a solution that works for me, with the help of the link provided by Tim Williams and also This previous post.
I updated my procedure to call a function that uses hwnd to find all open Excel instances and store them in a Collection. Then I remove the one collection item that I know I do not want to work with, which leaves me with just 1 instance in my collection.
From there I set a Workbook variable to for the instance/workbook that is in the collection and perform the Refresh.
Step 1 - Declarations
#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

  Private Declare Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal hwndChildAfter As Long, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long
#End If

Step 2 - The main Sub
Sub Refresh()
'***** Loop through all instances of Excel *****
  Dim xl As Excel.Application
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim wb As Workbook
  
  '***** Create a Collection of Excel Instances *****
  For Each xl In GetExcelInstances()
    '***** Print the details of the remaining Excel instance in the Collection *****
'    Debug.Print "Handle: " & xl.Application.hwnd
'    Debug.Print "# workbooks: " & xl.Application.Workbooks.Count
    For i = 1 To xl.Application.Workbooks.Count
'        Debug.Print "Workbook: " & xl.Application.Workbooks(i).Name
'        Debug.Print "Workbook path: " & xl.Application.Workbooks(i).Path
    Next i
    
    '***** Set workbook as the 1 remaining workbook from the collection *****
    Set wb = xl.Application.Workbooks(1)
    wb.RefreshAll
    wb.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

  Next
  Set xl = Nothing
'    Do Until wb.Application.CalculationState = "xlDone"
'    Loop
'
End Sub

Step 3 - Function being called to create the collection
Private Function GetExcelInstances() As Collection
'***** Function to create collection of Excel instances based on hwnd *****
    Dim guid&(0 To 3), acc As Object, hwnd, hwnd2, hwnd3
    guid(0) = &H20400
    guid(1) = &H0
    guid(2) = &HC0
    guid(3) = &H46000000
    Dim AlreadyThere As Boolean
    Dim xl As Application
    Set GetExcelInstances = New Collection
    Do
        hwnd = FindWindowExA(0, hwnd, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        If hwnd = 0 Then Exit Do
        hwnd2 = FindWindowExA(hwnd, 0, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
        hwnd3 = FindWindowExA(hwnd2, 0, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
        If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd3, &HFFFFFFF0, guid(0), acc) = 0 Then
            AlreadyThere = False
            For Each xl In GetExcelInstances
                If xl Is acc.Application Then
                    '***** Do not add to the collection if it is already there *****
                    AlreadyThere = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            '***** If the window is not already in the collection then add it *****
            If Not AlreadyThere Then
                GetExcelInstances.Add acc.Application
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    '***** Remove the 1st item from the collection because it is the Bot Settings file (we don't want to work with this file) *****
    GetExcelInstances.Remove (1)
End Function

